# How to remove duplicate rows from a Data Table

Tags: powershell, datatable

How to remove duplicate rows from a DataTable?

I have a `Datatable1` & `Datatable2`. `Datatable1` has 5 rows and `Datatable2` has 1 row.

When I called `$Datatable1.Merge($Datatable2)`, it is resulting in 7 rows instead of 6 rows.
The duplicate row is from `Datatable2`.

How can I remove this duplicate one?

Comment: Please do not edit an answer into a question. If you found a solution yourself it's perfectly acceptable to post it as an answer of your own.

Comment: Previously, i was unable to add my solution as i don't have enough reputation points and permissions. So i edited my question and added my solution.

Comment: Please don't do that. Questions are questions are questions. Not answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the OP's own solution as an actual answer:

```
function RemoveDups {
    Param($dt)

    $distinct = New-Object "System.Data.DataTable" 
    $hash = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]"

    foreach ($column in $dt.Columns) {
        $distinct.Columns.Add($column.ToString()) | Out-Null
    }

    foreach ($row in $dt.rows) {
        $columnsToCheck = [string]($row.COLUMNNAME)
        $result = $hash.Add($columnsToCheck)

        if ($result -eq $true) {
            [void]$distinct.Rows.Add($row.ItemArray)
        }
    }
    return ,$distinct
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$Datatable1.Merge($Datatable2)
$Datatable1=$Datatable1.DefaultView.ToTable($true)
```

Comment: I tried it. But it is showing that there is no "ToTable".

Comment: Your object is really a datatable? Because ToTable exists since Framework 2.0 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/wec2b2e6(v=vs.110).aspx)